# HttpPut attributed method won't do model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an API project in .net core and am running into an issue. I can't bind the Client model to the 'client' variable in the below method, note that it worked with a `[HttpPost]` attributed method.

**CODE**

```
[Route("client/{id}")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult UpdateClient(string id, [FromBody] Client client)
{ 
    try
    {
        ObjectId objectid = new ObjectId(id);

        Client update = _oauthRepository.GetClient(objectid);

        if(update != null)
        {
            _oauthRepository.UpdateClient(objectid, client);

            return Json(objectid);
        }

        return Json(false);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**POSTMAN**

```
[Method: PUT] url: http://localhost:50122/client/5aeb1a29405f2558bc6eac84
Body (JSON(application/json)):

{
    "BsonID": "5aeb1a29405f2558bc6eac84",
    "clientID": "blaatje",
    "clientSecrets": [
        "secret"
    ],
    "allowedScopes": "api"
}
```

**CLIENT MODEL**

```
namespace AuthServer.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId BsonID { get; set; }
        public string ClientID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
        public string AllowedScopes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `id` in this url `http://localhost:50122/client`? What do you mean by "won't do model binding" ? `Client client` is null or it not step into method when PUT?

Comment: Well, normally .net will transform the sent json string into a model when the receiving method expects a model and the json string exactly matches the props of that model. I forgot to state the id in the calling url.

Comment: So when you run this, the client is null?

Comment: Yes it is null, I would expect it to bind to the Client model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I figured it out. It didn't like the BsonID parameter, probably because it was an MongoDB attributed property [BsonId], this is converted to _id by the MongoDB driver. See the request below.

**POSTMAN**

```
[Method: PUT] url: http://localhost:50122/client/5aeb1a29405f2558bc6eac84
Body (JSON(application/json)):

{
    //"BsonID": "5aeb1a29405f2558bc6eac84", // <-- Leave this line out and it works, probably because this is a MongoDB attributed property
    "clientID": "blaatje",
    "clientSecrets": [
        "secret"
    ],
    "allowedScopes": "api"
}
```

Now on to the next error but that one lies beyond the scope of this question :)